# $http.success() or .error() not triggering ng-show upon completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

After posting a form to a web service, the below angular http post result should trigger one of two HTML elements to display the success or failure of the post. Though I'm getting a 200 ok reponse along with a "Success" string as a return, the success HTML element isn't displaying as if it wasn't successful. Can anyone point out what I'm missing here? I'd appreciate it.

Jquery:

```
$scope.demoInquiry = function(){
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost:XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX',
            data : $.param({
                firstName : $scope.firstName,
                lastName : $scope.lastName,
                companyName : $scope.companyName,
                email : $scope.email,
                phone : $scope.phone,
                deviceHwid : "Website Inquiry"
            }),
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.postSuccess = true;
        }).error(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.postError = true;
        });
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="postSuccess">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3 col-xs-12 hidden">
                <span id="demoSuccessResult" style="color: blue;">Thank you for registering!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ng-show="postError">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3 col-xs-12 ">
                <span id="demoErrorResult" style="color: red;">There was an error with your registration. Try again.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the scope of the dom element is the same as that where you set postSuccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a hidden attribute on the nested div element. That's probably your problem.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was.

Comment: Second pair of eyes often helps in these situations!

Answer (score 0):

Add `$scope.$apply()` after changing the scope. This could help

Comment: Aren't events and http callbacks already wrapped in $apply()?